# How to set Viewcontroller before SWRevealViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swrevealviewcontroller

I want to add `SWRevealViewController` before my V1 and V2 controller. I don't know how to initiate the `reveal-controlle`.I added screen shots of my storyboard so its easy to understands all.[image]

Comment: you want to add new view controller  before swreaveal controller?

Comment: u want output like your screenshot?

Comment: yes i want to like that

Comment: set initial viewcontroller in your login screen

Comment: give storyboard identifier in revealvewcontroller.than apply presentview controller

Comment: Yes i already set.  
Initial -> V1 - > push next -> V2  now when push next controller it will be v3 my reveal controller

Comment: profile vc is vc2 ya vc1

Comment: It is my ------vc2

Comment: ok than i post my answer  check it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first extend your vc3 in any class.than apply storyboard identifier name in vc3.
write code in vc2 button click action method

```
vc3 *secondViewController =
    [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"storyboardidentifier name"];
[self presentViewController:second animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow this link

http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-sidebar-navigation-menu/

Do as it says. In the view controller where you want your slide out menu use this

```
    [menuBtn addTarget:self.revealViewController action:@selector(revealToggle:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer];
```

Make reveal view controller your initial view controller.